# How can I start a Windows child-process with the same user but cased differently?

Tags: c#, windows

My Windows service is running as `USER1234`. It needs to start a child-process for a third-party utility that has to run as `user1234` i.e. the same user that my service is running under, just in lower case. It's a quirk in how this third-party takes the user it is running under and passes its name on to another service that forces me to go down this route.

The various versions of `Process.Create()` (.NET framework) or `CreateProcessXYZ` (native API) enable me to either start a child process as the same user (i.e. in upper case) or as another user in which case I need to provide username *and* password.

My service does not know the password of its own user and for security reasons I would like to keep it that way.

Is there a way to generate some kind of token from my current process and use that in combination with the lower-case user name to start a new process? Or have `user1234` impersonate `USER1234` somehow?

Comment: Kerberos actually is case-sensitive, meaning domain controllers care about the case of the user name for purposes of hashing (although Windows is set up in such a way that it can jump through hoops to hide this fact). So if the user name really *is* `USER1234`, there should be no way to start a process as `user1234` -- at the first authentication attempt it will be "corrected" to the canonical user name. As to what user name a process sees, that would depend on how it's *actually* getting it, but I don't think you can influence that by trying to be clever with the credential.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried with the `runas` utility and a process started as "user1234" with the password from USER1234 does start and behave as expected.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I only checked in Task Manager for the credential and that does show the canonical user name (same thing in Process Explorer), but something like `cmd` does get a different user name in the environment block (and presumably you'd also get back something different from a `GetUserName` call).

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but is it an option to run your service as `user1234` rather than `USER1234`, or would that break other things? The interface for configuring services will look up the "real" user name, but the SCM doesn't care what we put in there and we could use a different case. (Haven't tested if this affects how the service gets its own user name, though.)

Comment: I had thought about that as well, but it would be a very global solution to a local problem, as there is a lot more going on in that service and its other child-processes that may or may not depend on the current capitalization of the username. But maybe messing with the environment block of the child-process is an avenue I could explore (if that is where the utility is getting the username from). Not very elegant, but preferable to handling passwords.